# Why "this" pointer has same value inside derived and first base class

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, this, multiple-inheritance

Consider these classes that will act as base classes:

```
struct Base1 {
   int b1;
   void print_Base1_addr() const { std::cout << this << '\n'; }
};

struct Base2 {
   int b2;
   void print_Base2_addr() const { std::cout << this << '\n'; }
};
```

If `Derived` inherits from `Base1` and `Base2`:

```
struct Derived: Base1, Base2 {
   int i;
   void print_addr() const { std::cout << this << '\n'; }
};
```

Then this code prints the same address for `this` in `Derived` and `Base1` but not in `Base2`:

```
Derived d{}; 

d.print_addr();
d.print_Base1_addr();
d.print_Base2_addr();
```

I don't understand why `this` in `Derived` has the same address as in `Base1`. These aren't empty classes as they all contain a data member (the addresses of the data members `b1` and `i`  differ). It is as if `Base1` overlaps on the `Derived`.

What I am overlooking?

Comment: The values are the same but the types are different.

Comment: `Derived` layout is roughly `[Base1 Base2 i]` (and not `[i Base1 Base2]`).

Comment: Another thought: `void print_Base1_addr() const { std::cout << this << " " << &b1 << '\n'; }` and you'll note that member variable b1 also has the same address as the Base1 object itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't understand why this in Derived has the same address as in Base1.

Why not? The derived object contains the base class subobjects. Sub objects can have the same address as the container object.

The layout in memory probably looks something like this:

```
mem addr   | 0123456789ab # relative to the address of Derived object
Base1      | 1111         # 1 denotes address occupied by Derived::Base1
Base2      |     2222     # 2 denotes address occupied by Derived::Base2
i          |         iiii # i denotes address occupied by Derived::i
Derived    | DDDDDDDDDDDD # D denotes address occupied by Derived
-------------------------
all subobj | 11112222iiii
```

Notice how the beginning of both 1 and D overlap at the address 0.

> It is as if Base1 overlaps on the Derived.

That is exactly how subobjects behave. Just like elements of array overlap the entire array, members of a class overlap the class, so too the base class sub objects overlap the memory of the derived class.

Answer (score 1):

Derived classes simply extend any base classes. In the end, it's all one object that starts at the same address.

In your example, `d` is an instance of that resulting class. It will always have the same starting address.